# Migrating to android studio 3.0.1

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

Hello i am trying to migrate my project to android 3.0.1 how ever i get below error :

> Error:(1, 0) Unable to find method
>   'org.gradle.api.Project.getPluginManager()Lorg/gradle/api/plugins/PluginManager;'.
>   Possible causes for this unexpected error include:
>
> - Gradle's
>     dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network
>     connection timeout.) Re-download dependencies
>     and sync project (requires network)
> - The state of a Gradle
>     build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may
>     solve this problem. Stop Gradle build
>     processes (requires restart)
> - Your project may be using a
>     third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in
>     the project or the version of Gradle requested by the
>     project.
>
> In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can
>   also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java
>   processes.

I tried to add google() to repositories but got
 no where

my gradle build is :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 20
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.flashlight"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 14
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
```

Comment: In case it help , i am using android studio 3.0.1 and This is a Link to the source Code :  http://www.mediafire.com/file/555cmrttst47za0/FlashLight_AndroidStudio.zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `gradle-wrapper.properties` to:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the current gradle files are incompatible with your latest Android Studio version. You can just delete the .gradle folder as it is always created when the tasks are run. Deleting the folder will cause all the dependencies to download again (which will take some time) and then you can try to re-run the application.
You need internet connection for syncing and downloading the gradle files. Let me know if the error still persists.

Comment: i tried to change my gradle version to 3.0.1 
AND I CHANGED   minSdkVersion TO 15
compileSdkVersion to  26
but nothing workd 

 i m getting this error : 
Error:(21, 9) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompact-v7:26.0.0-beta1

Comment: @Heraculassen you are welcome. Please mark the solution as accepted so that other users with same doubt can benefit from the solution. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This code is tested and it works :

change your ***gradle*** file like this :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.flashlight"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 25
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
}

 dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
}
```

alse in ***gradle-wrapper.properties*** file make distribution url :

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip
```

in ***build.gradle*** change **com.android.tools.build:gradle** version to :

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'
```

Answer (score 0):

Finaly probleme solved , it was just a litlle probleme of gradle version , seems i had to update the source code manualy .
thanks guys